# Reflecting and counting points on a 2D grid

Tags: java, homework, coordinate-system

> First number indicates the number of points, followed by N points
>   (x,y). Then the next number indicates Q num_queries,  followed by Q queries:
>
> 1. Reflect all points between point i and j both including along the
>      X axis. This query is represented as "X i j"
> 2. Reflect all points between point i and j both including along the Y axis. This query is
>      represented as "Y i j"
> 3. Count how many points between point i and j both including lie in each of the 4 quadrants. This query is
>      represented as "C i j"
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4         
> 1 1         
> -1 1         
> -1 -1
> 1 -1
> 5
> C 1 4
> X 2 4
> C 3 4
> Y 1 2
> C 1 3
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 0 0
> 0 2 0 1
> ```

How can i improve this code for better metrics?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author cypronmaya
 */
class Point {

    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class Quad_query {

    private ArrayList<Point> arrayList;

    public Quad_query(int capacity) {
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Point>(capacity);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num_of_points = scanner.nextInt();
        Quad_query quad_query = new Quad_query(num_of_points);
        for (int i = num_of_points; --i >= 0;) {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            int y = scanner.nextInt();
            quad_query.add(x, y);
        }
        int num_of_queries = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = num_of_queries; --i >= 0;) {
            char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            quad_query.query(c, scanner.nextInt() - 1, scanner.nextInt() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void add(int x, int y) {
        Point point = new Point(x, y);
        arrayList.add(point);
    }

    public void query(char c, int i, int j) {

        switch (c) {
            case 'C':
                queryC(i, j);
                break;
            default:
                queryXY(c, i, j);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void queryC(int i, int j) {

        int quad_1 = 0, quad_2 = 0, quad_3 = 0, quad_4 = 0;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            Point pnt = arrayList.get(k);
            int pnt_x = pnt.x;
            int pnt_y = pnt.y;
            if (pnt_x > 0 && pnt_y > 0) {
                quad_1++;
            } else if (pnt_x < 0 && pnt_y > 0) {
                quad_2++;
            } else if (pnt_x < 0 && pnt_y < 0) {
                quad_3++;
            } else if (pnt_x > 0 && pnt_y < 0) {
                quad_4++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(quad_1 + " " + quad_2 + " " + quad_3 + " " + quad_4);
    }

    private void queryXY(char c, int i, int j) {

        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            Point pnt = arrayList.get(k);
            int pnt_x = pnt.x;
            int pnt_y = pnt.y;
            if (c == 'X') {
                pnt = new Point(pnt_x, -pnt_y);
            } else if (c == 'Y') {
                pnt = new Point(-pnt_x, pnt_y);
            }
            arrayList.set(k, pnt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the input you gave ?

As a first quick and useless comment, I would say that variable "num_of_points" is not really useful.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of initializing your arrayList when you create the instance of the class, do it when you have the num_of_points value from the scanner.

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<Point>(num_of_points);
```

This will mean the array list doesn't need to resize itself (potentially slow operation). In the example you have given with only 4 points it won't make any difference, but if there were a larger number of points you may save some time!

Where you get the value from the scanner `char c` you trim the value, which you shouldn't need to do as the Scanner should stop when it sees a delimiter (in this case, a space).

In the `queryC` method, you have a for loop...

```
for (int b = 0; b < len; b++) {
    pnt = arrayList.get(b);
}
```

...that does nothing, so you can remove it.

A few notes on code style...

- In the main method your for loops go from X down to 0, but in the query methods you go from 0 up to X. Just wondering why?
- You also use `(0 - pnt.x)` where you could use `-pnt.x`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry,i forgot to remove that useless loop before only,regarding (o-pnt.x) -- written simply, loops go down in main method from X->0  because i wouldn't use the loop variable in it,the way i've written loops in main method, would optimized one's

Comment: those trim, that i've done just for safety purposes,i know scanner would take exactly what to take, but simply, please look at modified version

Comment: @cypronmaya The only other thing I can see is that you have used variables ``int pnt_x = pnt.x`` I wouldn't bother with this variable as the compiler should inline it anyway. 
It is coded in a pretty readable manner which as @MikeNakis said, is the main thing to worry about.

Comment: Also you say that you write the for loops in the main method that way because you're not using the loop variable inside the loop - why not turn it into a much more readable while loop?

Comment: Ya, u've given lot of usefull inpur, but still i'm not able to achieve the req thing, execution time failed

Comment: before i could pass all testcases :(, donno what i'm doing wrong , all these modifications would only increase readability,optimized. May be my implementation is worse, if u've found any simpler form for this solution , i would be greatful

Comment: are you supposed to read from standard input? this would take a long time and would have significant effect on the time it takes for your program to complete. Could you read from file instead? It will read quicker from file as it's not waiting for you to type anything in.

Comment: no, i can't change rules, they will gimme in STDIN and should give output in STDOUT, they have their own testcases, constraints etc.,

Comment: Try putting arrayList.add and arrrayList.remove back in.

Comment: arrayList.set would combinedly do those right.....

Comment: it should do what you want it to do, but I wonder if it might be the change that has had a sudden performance hit on your code. None of the other changes should have affected it.

Comment: changes done to the initial one, done nothing(in metrics).... increased readability, cleaner version.

Answer (score 2):

`for (int i = num_of_queries; --i >=0;)` is cute, but it makes one pause for a moment and think whether it is correct or not before moving on. It is better rewritten as `for (int i = num_of_queries; i > 0;  i--)`.

Your arraylist is allocated once and never changed, (its contents are ganged, but not the object itself,) so it should be declared as `final`.  Right before you start using it, since you know how many items are going to go into it, do `arrayList.ensureCapacity(num_of_points);` so as to help it to avoid resizing itself as it is discovering its capacity by itself.

Use better names; `quad_qu` should be `quad_queue` or perhaps just `queue`.

In `QueryC`:

Get rid of the `pnt_x` and `pnt_y` variables and simply use `pnt.x` and `pnt.y` instead.

Declare `pnt` inside the loop, not outside it: `Point pnt = arrayList.get(k);`

Rename `pnt` to `point`, or `pt`, or just `p`.

In `QueryXY`:

Again, declare `pnt` inside the loop, not outside it.

Declare `new_pnt` inside the loop, too, and *do not initialize it to null*. It is bad practice to initialize things when there is no need. It prevents the compiler from giving you useful warnings. When you do this, the compiler will give you a warning that you may be trying to use `new_pnt` before you have assigned a value to it. That's because your if statement checks for `'X'`, and then for `'Y'`, but there is no `else` clause to handle any other possibility. So, add an `else` clause and throw an exception: `throw new Exception("wtf?")`

Get rid of these: `int pnt_x = 0, pnt_y = 0;` they are not used. Actually, the fact that you have these in your code, and you have not seen a compiler warning about them not being used, tells me that you are not compiling with all warnings enabled. Do yourself a favor and enable all warnings so as to have the compiler help you. That's his job.

Replace this:

```
arrayList.remove(k);
arrayList.add(k, new_pnt);
```

With simply this: `arrayList.set(k, new_pnt);`

Comment: Speaking of -> for (int i = num_of_queries; --i >=0;) is lot better, it removes useless checks and optimized.
-> ensureCapacity it's better only if i'm having lots of records, atleast more than 10(initial capacity).As i'm having very few records, i don't it doesn't really matter ....:P

Comment: Regarding names,un-necessary variables,declarations thanks. BTW i've initialized it to null as compiler thrown me a warning.
About replacing this "arrayList.remove(k);
arrayList.add(k, new_pnt);" ----> Here first i'm removing the element at pos-k and then inserting newly modified element at the same position. As u suggested arrayList.set(k, new_pnt); , what it does is , it doesn't replace the existing element, it only checks if an element exists, if so their index will be increased and new_element is inserted at tht position.

Comment: Regarding `ensureCapacity`, you are right. Regarding the `for` loop, the compiler will optimize it for you anyway, so you don't have to worry about it. Even if the compiler was not going to optimize it, readability is usually far more important than minuscule optimizations. The couple of seconds I wasted looking at it represent a much longer time period than the sum of all the nanoseconds that would ever be saved by this little optimization on all the runs of your application by all the users who will ever see it in all the years that it is going to be in use.

Comment: Regarding ->Get rid of the pnt_x and pnt_y variables and simply use pnt.x and pnt.y instead.-> If i didn't use pnt_x,pnt_y, every time is use pnt.x,pnt.y in if conditional's it has to calculate or get wht is pnt.x and pnt.y from object, so for that, i've assigned them to pnt_x,pnt_y, so that they don't have to be calculated again and again..

Comment: Can u comment on the approach i've followed? any unnecessary methods, unnecessary loops,is it too obvious or lengthy or lame one?. Can u suggest a good approach to solve this?

Comment: Regarding the initialization to null, the warning, and why you should do it the way I suggested, read this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6329/8381 starting from "One more note:"

Comment: arrayList.set( k, new_pnt ) will do exactly what I intended it to do; don't theorize about it when you can just look it up: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int, E)

Comment: Regarding pnt_x and pnt_y, studies have shown that when humans try to hand-optimize code at that level, the results are in most cases **worse** than if they had left the compiler do it for them, and in the majority of the remaining cases they are no better than what the compiler would have done by itself, anyway. Declaring your own variables instead of letting the compiler use what is known as "inference variables" is a typical example of such a well meant, but ill advised optimization.

Comment: Sorry about set method, ya it does exactly what u've said,i've forgot to see the name set,it  looked like add to me :P to say like that. Regarding initialization , i completely agree

Comment: In any case, my advise to you would be to stop worrying about performance so much. The rule in the industry is to code things in the simplest, most readable and most maintainable way possible, then establish performance requirements, then measure the software against these requirements, and if and only if the software fails to meet these requirements, go optimize that 1% of the code which will make the software meet the requirements. And usually, these optimizations turn out to be algorithmic, not hacky.

Comment: As to the approach you followed, no, I have nothing to say about that, it seems just fine to me.